# Maven Dependency Plugin Copy Artifact from Remote Repository

Tags: maven

I currently have an archiva remote repository setup on a server that I deploy my war files to.  I have a need to copy the war file from the remote repository into a directory on a server.  So I used the maven-dependency-plugin like so

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy \
-Dartifact=<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>:war \
-DoutputDirectory=/home/me/some/directory
```

Looking at the maven documentation, this command will resolve the dependency then copy it to the directory.  It downloads the dependency into this structure.

```
Directory struture
~/.m2/repository/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.war
```

After the artifact is in the local repository the copy command fails and says it can't find the artifact.

```
Unable to find artifact. 
Could not find artifact <groupId>:<artifactId>:war:<version>
```

Does this structure look correct?  The weird thing is the directory structure for junit is the same and when I run

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy \
-Dartifact=junt:junit:4.11:jar \
-DoutputDirectory=/home/me/some/directory
```

everything works.

Comment: Why not using curl for such things?

Comment: @khmarbaise because maven handles getting the most up to date snapshot.  I ended up using the `get` goal of the plugin to get the most up to date snapshot then using stat linux cmd to check if the file has been updated in my local repo.  If the date has changed I cp the war to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit a *similar* problem, but from Eclipse. Maybe this will help you.

I am using the `copy-dependencies` goal.

In my pom I had to define the remote repo as:

```
<repository>
    <id>http://maven.xwiki.org</id>
    <url>http://maven.xwiki.org/externals</url>
</repository>
```

Maven from CLI warns about the "://" characters in the above `id`, but if I remove them Maven from Eclipse fails to find the dependencies in the remote repo.